# SSRS set default values to display 1/1/1900 and 1/1/9999

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, datetime-format

I have two parameters start date min and Max both are optional parameters. I have the allow null values unchecked as that is the requirement. But by default need to 
display 1/1/1900 in the Min date text box 
and 1/1/9999 in Max date textbox.

I tried setting this value on my parameters properties using Datetime.MinValue which displays 1/1/0001 in my text box.

But when I run the report I get the error date time needs to be between 1/1/1753 and 12/31/9999
And for max date textbox I tried to use Datetime.Maxvalue and it throws error "MaxDate" is not valid for its type.
Could anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: Why cant you treat treat the absence of a value as Min and Max values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple you cannot set a minimum or maximum value for Parameters in SSRS, yes but you can provide a default value of 01/01/1900 for your datetime parameters.

Go to Report parameter properties and set a default value there.

[image]

When the report executes it will show the following:

[image]

You have little control over what user selects, hence using a stored procedure to validate the passed values from the end users is another option.